# Powerpoint 2016 - Inserting automatic titles/headers based on section name

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have my slides organised into sections, and would like each slide to automatically have its title (header) be of the form "SectionName >> Subtitle". SectionName should be the name of the section that contains the current slide, and Subtitle is text I would input manualy for each slide (ideally in text rather than slide view; for that I guess I'd have to use outlineView, and thus that my titles have to function as the slides' Title rather than as a simple text heading).

Also, is there any way to make sections organised hierarchically, much like Heading1, Heading2 etc styles in Word, and collapse a certain section with all of its subsections? If so, it would be excellent to have the titles actually named as "Section1Name>>Section2Name>>..>>ManualSubtitle".

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have anything like this built-in, but it should be possible with some VBA or other programming. If you have some VBA experience, give it a shot and if you get into trouble, post your code on StackOverflow and ask for help.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, converting Steve Rindsberg's comment into an answer:

PowerPoint has no function like this built-in.

However, like most Office products, PowerPoint does have the very powerful VBA macro engine, which would certainly be capable of doing this.

Your macro would have to capture the Section name based on whatever parameters you choose to use to mark that, and then it could place that information anywhere you please within subsequent slides.

Because slides are more about visual layout than programmatic auto-creation, this is something you'd have to build yourself.

But, also like Steve Rindsberg noted: Get something started and as you come upon questions, our programming sister site StackOverflow would be a great place to ask them.

Comment: That's very sensible advice, thank you.

Comment: Did anyone manage to do the macro? I am not a VBA programmer myself ^^